# FFT exponential form ends up in noisy audio

Tags: python, audio, fft

I'm working on a python script where I try to do manipulation of the phases of the FFT data. So the first step I've taken now is just to get the basics to work:

1. Do FFT
2. Normalize the data
3. Separate Amplitudes and Phases
4. Put Amps and Phases back together
5. Do IFFT
6. Check if it sounds how it should.

This far I've managed to do correctly steps 1 and 2. So the FFT with numpy RFFT goes alright, then the normalization works as well so when doing the IFFT and playing it again it sounds as it should. However separating the amps and phases and putting them back together introduces a lot of noise so something is going wrong. Here's my code using the Numpy and Scipy modules:

```
samplerate, data = wavfile.read(location)
audio = data.T[0] # first track of audio    
fftData = np.fft.rfft(audio[sample:], length)
fftData = np.divide(fftData, (np.median(fftData))) #normalization with median value
phas = np.angle(fftData) #calculating the phases
amps = np.abs(fftData) #calculating the amplitudes
#here I'd do the phase manipulation
phas = np.exp(phas) #transforming phases to exponential form
amps = np.multiply(amps,phas) #multiplying the amps with the exp form of phases to get the exponential form of the complex number
output = np.fft.irfft(amps).astype(dtype=np.float32) #doing the IRFFT, I use float32 because I play it back with py audio which uses float32.
```

So what am I doing wrong? I read from here: https://www.intmath.com/complex-numbers/5-exponential-form.php that you can have the complex number as exponential form so that you could have the phases and amplitudes as separate arrays. And according to that site joining the data should just be multiplication of the amps(magnitude) and the exponential form of the phases. So what have I misunderstood as it sounds REALLY noisy? I even tried to normalize it again after joining the phases and amps but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an exponential form for the phases, but you have to use complex exponentials. More specifically in your case `phas = np.angle(fftData0` is computed as a real-valued angle (in radians), so the phase angle argument to `exp` must first be multiplied by `1j`.

The correct complex exponential to use would then be:

```
phas = np.exp(np.multiply(1j, phas))
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot!